# WNetAddConection2() -Unicode

Tags: c#, unicode

I have an application which can access shared drives within the network. The same has been achieved using P-Invoke **WNetAddConection2()** Win API. Everything was working well until we introduce Unicode support in our application,  now the application is failing whenever we provide a shared path containing some Unicode characters like for eg:

```
        Input 1:   \\domain\shared-folder : this works fine
        Input 2:   \\domain\    : this fails, the method return an error
```

Do we have any alternative to WNetAddConection2()  which supports Unicode, I have already tried by encoding the 
given path as path.encode('UTF16') but its not working. We use c# as programming language.

Comment: This is what happens when you pass an 8-bit encoded string to a Unicode function.  Clearly your pinvoke declaration is wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks for the reply: How can I resolve this issue, is there any other win api to handle the problem

Comment: If the pinvoke declaration were wrong, Input 1 would fail too.

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer and HansPassant: thanks for pointing out the error, I got the right api, which is **WNetAddConnection2W()** designed to accept unicode characters, I am able to get the required output